# Could not get property unknown property '' for a task

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

Working to get Gradle to generate a CSV file and trying to create properties for my build.gradle file that can be passed in from the command line.

I've inserted the following into gradle.properties:

```
userCount=100
```

In my build.gradle file

```
    task writeUsersFile << {
    if (project.hasProperty('userCount')){
        args = getProperty(userCount)
    }
    outputFile.withWriter { out ->
    1.upto($userCount) {
      out.println(String.format(userNameFmt, it, testPassword))
    } 
  } 
}
```

When I run the Gradle process via the command line I encounter the following:

```
Could not get unknown property '100' for task ':writeUsersFile' of type org.gradle.api.DefaultTask.
```

If I pass the parameter in from the command line, it's appropriately updating the error from the default of '100' to the value I'm passing.

Have also tried:

```
task writeUsersFile << {
    userCount = project.hasProperty('userCount') ? project.userCount : ''
    outputFile.withWriter { out ->
    1.upto($userCount) {
      out.println(String.format(userNameFmt, it, testPassword))
    }
  }
}
```

and that results in:

```
Could not get unknown property '$userCount' for task ':writeUsersFile' of type org.gradle.api.DefaultTask.
```

The writing of the file is working fine if I define `userCount=100` (or whatever arbitrary number) directly in my build.gradle, the roadblock is setting the argument for the # of users.

Comment: Did my answer solve your problem? If yes, would you mind to accept the answer to mark this question solved? See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). If no, please add more detail to your question or what you're missing about the answer.

Comment: Your answer helped push me towards the correct answer. I was still running into issues when declaring the property in the task block. I took your advice to use just 'userCount' and will add what solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following changes resolved the issue I was encountering. When I used `userCount` directly in the `upto()` method call I was encountering a parsing issue. The following block resolves the error message and subsequent parsing issue:

```
task writeUsersFile << {
    outputFile.withWriter { out ->
    1.upto(Integer.parseInt(userCount)) {
      out.println(String.format(userNameFmt, it, testPassword))
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use `userCount` without using `getProperty` and the notation `$userCount` is only evaluated in double quoted strings:

```
task writeUsersFile << {
    t_userCount = project.hasProperty('userCount') ? userCount : 0
    outputFile.withWriter { out ->
    1.upto(t_userCount) {
      out.println(String.format(userNameFmt, it, testPassword))
    }
  }
}
```